# find the corresponding control in repeater control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, repeater

I have a `Repeater` control which contains a `CheckBox` and a lable control in each row. When a `CheckBox` is selected. I want to retrieve the text of the `Label` for the corresponding `CheckBox`. How to get it?

Comment: Try accessing the parent of the checkbox (which should be the repeater) and then get the child which the label corresponds to.

Comment: use javascript or jquery, write a function on checked event and get value from label

Comment: You have about 30 questions with no accepted answers !! try to accept some of them starting with this one :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the `CheckBox.Checked` event handler:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) sender;
Label label = (Label) checkBox.Parent.FindControl("LabelName");
String labelText = label.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ItemCommand` event of the Repeater as follows:

```
protected void rep1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.CommandName == "Command") 
        { 
            Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("labelID") as Label; 
            lbl.Text //
            CheckBox chk= e.Item.FindControl("chkId") as CheckBox; 
            chk.Checked //
        } 

    }
```

You can get a better idea from this article: [ASP.Net Repeater OnItemCommand Event using C#](http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-Repeater-OnItemCommand-Event-using-C-sharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

rowcommand event or rowdatabound event, find the 2 controls values from row in that event and get and use values . for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: you will register a javascript function in that event to retrieve label value